# SOQL Group by IN Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, soql, group

```
String query = 'SELECT id,CreatedById,Product.Id,POCGrades__c ,fm_pocname__c,product.Name ,Visit.placeId, fm_poccode__c, createdby.LastName,Visit.LastModifiedDate, createddate, ActualBooleanValue'
                + ' FROM retailvisitkpi'
                + ' WHERE createddate = last_month and '
                + ' ( Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tszWAAQ\''
                + ' OR Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tszWAAQ\''
                + ' OR Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tt5nAAA\''
                + ' OR Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tsznAAA\''
                + ' OR Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tt1zAAA\''
                + ' OR Product.Id = \'01t5j000003tt7AAAQ\'' 
                + ' )';
```

I am having trouble to removes duplicate records based on Visit.placeID, can anybody help me out with soql

Answer (score 0):

Just use hashmaps with the resulting query?

```
Map<String, retailvisitkpi__c> mapOfItems = new Map<String, retailvisitkpi__c>();
```

That will remove all the duplicates based on the Visit Place ID